# Linking HTML and CSS that are in different folders

Tags: html, css

I have the following folders structure: one SITE folder and inside of it i have a HTML folder (where lies my index.html file) and a CSS folder (where lies my main.css file).

What's the right way to link my css file to my index.html? I've tried some relative paths, but i haven't got it right yet.

Comment: If SITE is the root web folder you should be able to do <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/main.css">  Also if SITE is the root folder you may want index.html in that folder and not in HTML folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like this is what you need:

```
SITE
|
+--- HTML
|    |
|    +--- index.html
+--- CSS
     |
     +--- main.css
```

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/main.css">
```

First you navigate out of your current folder ("..") and then into your CSS folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

- Your Site folder

  - HTML
  - CSS

You should be able to do the following within the HEAD section:

  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/main.css">`

This goes up one folder from the HTML file to the root folder, then selects the CSS folder followed by the main.css file

A great resource is https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Hope this makes sense